# Image paths are breaking in ReactJs in production?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I made an app on ReactJS with create-react-app. Paths to images are breaking in Production mode in subpages. I used react-router. 
The Structure of project looks like this static/media/image.jpg
Paths in subpages are getting like this site.com/product/product-one/static/media/image.jpg

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Path should be relative to the root of the project. e.g. if root of the project is site.com then image path should be `/product/product-one/static/media/image.jpg` and not `static/media/image.jpg`. You can also try putting them in public folder.

Answer (score 0):

The static directory is outside the src? If that is the case you have to specify in the webpack.